# How to get subdomain in Route 53 to resolve to Internet-facing Elastic Load Balancer?

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, cname-record, amazon-route53

I own a domain, call it [doggos.lol](http://doggos.lol) that uses Route 53 for DNS. I want to create a subdomain elb.doggos.lol that resolves to the public DNS of an ELB. I created a CNAME to route elb.doggos.lol to an Alias target (the ELB public DNS).

I saved the record but the route is not working.  If I execute an HTTP request against the public DNS of the ELB, I get the correct REST response from the server it sends to.  However, if I go to the subdomain in the CNAME record, I get DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.  Testing the CNAME record on Route 53 returns a REFUSED DNS response code.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure the cname is correct? Did you use FQDN for target of the record?

Comment: yes the cname on route 53 is named elb.doggos.lol and the FQDN of the alias target will hit that endpoint if you paste into the address bar.  Very confused why I'm getting DNS REFUSED.

Comment: so there is something like ``elb.doggox.lol`` (CNAME) => ``public-elb.doggox.lol`` ?

Comment: @NeilPhilip please provide the real domain or use the officially established example names like http://example.com et al. rather than making up domain names.

Comment: Hi @KamilJ, precisely elb.doggos.lol (CNAME) =>  example-1.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out for Alias targets, you must use an A record (or AAAA for IPv6). I switched the record from CNAME to A and this resolved the problem.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-create-alias-records/